# How to use [[Text]] tag for text block in Advanced TXT file for Qualtrics survey?

Tags: qualtrics

I want to create an Advanced TXT file for importing a survey into qualtrics.

This [help file](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/survey-tools/general-tools/import-and-export-surveys/) says that you can include text/graphic descriptive block.

Specifically, you are meant to be able to use the following tags:

```
[[Text]] or [[DB]] – Text/Graphic (Descriptive Block)
```

However, the help file does not provide any examples of how it is meant to be used. And when I try the obvious options, I get the following error message on import:

```
Error parsing file (line 5) invalid directive Text
```

I've tried a few things.

Option 1:

```
[[Text]]
Here is some text
```

Option 2:

```
[[Text:foo]]
Here is some text
```

Option 3:

```
[[Text]]
[[ID:foo]]
Here is some text
```

They all generate the same error.

Thus, the question is:
**How do you use  the[[Text]] tag for text blocks in Advanced TXT file for a Qualtrics survey?**

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
[[Question:DB]]
[[ID:foo]]
This is text
```